# PWA - schedule notification typescript error 'showTrigger' does not exist in type 'NotificationOptions'

Tags: typescript, progressive-web-apps

I am building progressive web app and we need to send local notification as a reminder to complete a form on our app every week.

Based on research (https://web.dev/notification-triggers/), I found chrome and firefox support showTrigger currently in trial and i was testing locally but visual studio throws error as 'showTrigger' does not exist in type 'NotificationOptions'.

Error:

```
Type '{ tag: string; body: string; icon: string; data: { url: string; }; showTrigger: any; }' is not assignable to type 'NotificationOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'showTrigger' does not exist in type 'NotificationOptions'.
```

Code:

```
export const createScheduledNotification = async () => {
    const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration();
    const timestamp = new Date().getTime() + 5 * 1000;

    registration?.showNotification("PWA App", {
      tag: "1234",
      body: "This notification was scheduled 30 seconds ago",
      showTrigger: new TimestampTrigger(timestamp + 30 * 1000)
    });
};
```

software version:

```
vscode: 1.52.2
typescript: 4.1.2
```

Update 1
I tried to add a new file `Notification.d.ts` as below but now getting error at runtime.

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: TimeStampTrigger is not defined
```

Code:

```
interface NotificationOptions {
    showTrigger: TimeStampTrigger
}

declare class TimeStampTrigger {
    constructor(timestamp: DOMTimeStamp);
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled the `#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` flag in Chrome, or signed up for an origin trial? Without doing that, the APIs won't be available.

Comment: @PeteLe i have enabled that flag in chrome but the error is when i try to build in vscode. It seems `NotificationOptions` missing `showTrigger` in `lib.webworker.d.ts`. How can i extend and add a custom `.d.ts`?

Comment: Added update but now getting error at runtime.

Comment: Have you tried treating the `showTrigger` part `as any`?